# How to build permutation with some conditions in R

Tags: r, permutation

I am new to R and I am a little confused. Suppose I have a vector of c(1,2,3,4,5,6). I would like to generate permutations with four elements and every permutation should involve 1 and 5. Thank you.

Comment: Refer to the linked Q & A. Use `MixedCombnPerm(list(c(1,5), c(2,3,4,6)), c(2, 2), TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`permutations()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.5.0/topics/combinations) from the `gtools` package to get the permuations, and [`filter_all()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter_all.html) from `dplyr` to get just the ones with 1 and 5:

```
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)

data <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

permutations(n = 6, r = 4, v = data, repeats.allowed = FALSE) %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(. == 5)) %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(. == 1))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 144 x 4
      V1    V2    V3    V4
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     2     3     5
 2     1     2     4     5
 3     1     2     5     3
 4     1     2     5     4
 5     1     2     5     6
 # ...
```