# Algorithm for best sum combination from 3 groups list

Tags: r

I have multi group of data like:

```
X <-  c(2,3,5,10,15) 
Y <- c(4,6,23,15,12) 
Z <- c(23,34,12,1,5)
```

and a target: `target = 50`

I want to know the best (for example): 2 values from X (call it X2), 4 values from Y (Y4) and 3 values from Z (Z3) that if I sum them I get `sum(X2) + sum(Y4) + sum(Z3) = 50` (or the closest to 50).

Is there a solution to this problem?

**Edit: The data I've provided is just an example… My end goal is to reproduce it on a large data.**

Here's my large data:

```
target <- 362007 

X <- c(1782L, 1780L, 1783L, 1784L, 1783L, 1781L, 1782L, 1781L, 1782L, 
1782L, 1782L, 1784L, 1780L, 1784L, 1782L, 1779L, 1782L, 1784L, 
1783L, 1782L, 1781L, 1777L, 1784L, 1782L, 1784L, 1784L, 1784L, 
1782L, 1784L, 1782L, 1783L, 1783L, 1785L, 1782L, 1781L, 1782L, 
1788L, 1789L, 1786L, 1787L, 1786L, 1783L, 1781L, 1781L, 1786L, 
1787L, 1786L, 1786L, 1785L, 1785L, 1784L, 1786L, 1785L, 1784L, 
1786L, 1785L, 1785L, 1783L, 1787L, 1787L, 1786L, 1785L, 1788L, 
1786L, 1788L, 1786L, 1780L, 1788L, 1785L, 1784L, 1786L, 1784L, 
1785L, 1783L, 1785L, 1785L, 1785L, 1786L, 1784L, 1784L, 1785L, 
1784L, 1785L, 1787L, 1786L, 1788L, 1785L, 1785L, 1780L, 1787L, 
1784L, 1785L, 1787L, 1784L, 1780L, 1785L, 1782L, 1787L, 1786L, 
1781L, 1780L, 1784L, 1785L, 1785L, 1785L, 1785L, 1785L, 1782L, 
1783L, 1787L, 1784L, 1783L, 1783L, 1782L, 1785L, 1783L, 1783L, 
1782L, 1786L, 1783L, 1786L, 1782L, 1783L, 1786L, 1784L, 1782L, 
1782L, 1785L, 1785L, 1783L, 1782L, 1781L, 1782L, 1779L, 1781L, 
1781L, 1785L, 1780L, 1782L, 1781L, 1782L, 1786L, 1786L, 1787L, 
1781L, 1780L, 1788L, 1781L, 1781L, 1780L, 1787L, 1787L, 1787L, 
1780L, 1786L, 1786L, 1779L, 1785L, 1792L, 1788L, 1781L, 1784L, 
1780L, 1784L, 1783L, 1785L, 1783L, 1783L, 1781L, 1783L, 1785L, 
1783L, 1785L, 1782L, 1785L, 1782L, 1782L, 1782L, 1779L, 1787L, 
1784L, 1783L, 1783L, 1786L, 1785L, 1787L, 1785L, 1783L, 1783L, 
1786L, 1784L, 1778L, 1787L, 1786L, 1784L, 1784L, 1781L, 1779L, 
1782L, 1786L, 1781L, 1787L, 1783L, 1781L, 1781L, 1786L, 1787L, 
1780L, 1779L, 1785L, 1784L, 1781L, 1783L, 1782L, 1781L, 1781L, 
1787L, 1785L, 1787L, 1784L, 1784L, 1783L, 1782L, 1785L, 1785L, 
1783L, 1779L, 1786L, 1780L, 1778L, 1783L, 1785L, 1780L, 1786L, 
1784L, 1779L, 1779L, 1779L, 1785L, 1780L, 1786L, 1778L, 1782L, 
1779L, 1779L, 1784L, 1780L, 1780L, 1785L, 1781L, 1778L, 1787L, 
1781L, 1786L, 1783L, 1784L, 1785L, 1786L, 1784L, 1782L, 1784L, 
1785L, 1786L, 1786L, 1785L, 1782L, 1786L, 1783L, 1783L, 1788L, 
1779L, 1786L, 1787L, 1781L, 1780L, 1780L, 1782L, 1784L, 1787L, 
1780L, 1786L, 1786L, 1786L, 1784L, 1787L, 1785L, 1784L, 1784L, 
1784L, 1781L, 1784L, 1784L, 1786L, 1784L, 1783L, 1784L, 1786L, 
1787L, 1786L, 1786L, 1785L, 1786L, 1785L, 1785L)

Y <- c(1786L, 1786L, 1786L, 1786L, 1787L, 1784L, 1782L, 1787L, 1786L, 
1786L, 1781L, 1787L, 1782L, 1785L, 1785L, 1786L, 1783L, 1781L, 
1787L, 1780L, 1785L, 1783L, 1787L, 1785L, 1786L, 1789L, 1784L, 
1785L, 1782L, 1780L, 1783L, 1786L, 1784L, 1782L, 1781L, 1788L, 
1785L, 1779L, 1782L, 1781L, 1781L, 1785L, 1781L, 1786L, 1784L, 
1782L, 1783L, 1782L, 1783L, 1784L, 1786L, 1780L, 1784L, 1782L, 
1779L, 1783L, 1789L, 1783L, 1782L, 1786L, 1784L, 1783L, 1788L, 
1786L, 1788L, 1783L, 1785L, 1787L, 1787L, 1784L, 1784L, 1787L, 
1783L, 1782L, 1787L, 1788L, 1786L, 1786L, 1785L, 1787L, 1782L, 
1787L, 1782L, 1787L, 1783L, 1787L, 1783L, 1784L, 1782L, 1782L, 
1784L, 1784L, 1786L, 1782L, 1780L, 1786L, 1783L, 1787L, 1785L, 
1786L, 1783L, 1783L, 1780L, 1781L, 1782L, 1788L, 1782L, 1783L, 
1785L, 1785L, 1783L, 1786L, 1785L, 1786L, 1780L, 1782L, 1785L, 
1784L, 1787L, 1779L, 1783L, 1782L, 1785L, 1780L, 1780L, 1786L, 
1782L, 1785L, 1785L, 1779L, 1783L, 1786L, 1787L, 1789L, 1782L, 
1781L, 1783L, 1780L, 1784L, 1783L, 1784L, 1784L, 1785L, 1785L, 
1786L, 1782L, 1782L, 1781L, 1783L, 1787L, 1784L, 1785L, 1782L, 
1781L, 1786L, 1784L, 1783L, 1784L, 1786L, 1784L, 1781L, 1783L, 
1786L, 1784L, 1782L, 1782L, 1786L, 1783L, 1782L, 1784L, 1786L, 
1784L, 1786L, 1783L, 1788L, 1782L, 1782L, 1787L, 1780L, 1781L, 
1782L, 1787L, 1785L, 1781L, 1781L, 1783L, 1787L, 1785L, 1786L, 
1783L, 1786L, 1780L, 1785L, 1786L, 1786L, 1781L, 1786L, 1786L, 
1787L, 1786L, 1783L, 1789L, 1785L, 1782L, 1789L, 1788L, 1784L, 
1782L, 1783L, 1781L, 1784L, 1783L, 1783L, 1787L, 1784L, 1783L, 
1781L, 1783L, 1787L, 1783L, 1786L, 1791L, 1782L, 1788L, 1786L, 
1785L, 1782L, 1787L, 1782L, 1784L, 1782L, 1782L, 1781L, 1782L, 
1784L, 1783L, 1783L, 1784L, 1780L, 1787L, 1783L, 1785L, 1782L, 
1786L, 1782L, 1787L, 1785L, 1782L, 1785L, 1784L, 1786L, 1783L, 
1781L, 1782L, 1781L, 1785L, 1782L, 1783L, 1784L, 1782L, 1782L, 
1784L, 1783L, 1787L, 1786L, 1786L, 1781L, 1782L, 1785L, 1787L, 
1784L, 1782L, 1788L, 1782L, 1783L, 1783L, 1785L, 1781L, 1780L, 
1786L, 1785L, 1780L, 1781L, 1782L, 1787L, 1784L, 1780L, 1782L, 
1781L, 1781L, 1780L, 1784L, 1782L, 1792L, 1787L, 1782L, 1779L, 
1784L, 1785L, 1786L, 1782L, 1786L, 1785L, 1785L, 1784L, 1785L, 
1783L, 1786L, 1785L, 1783L, 1782L, 1784L, 1781L, 1782L, 1784L, 
1786L, 1783L, 1783L, 1781L, 1785L, 1779L, 1783L, 1781L, 1781L, 
1786L, 1783L, 1781L, 1787L, 1782L, 1787L, 1786L, 1645L, 1788L, 
1783L, 1786L, 1787L, 1783L, 1780L, 1781L, 1782L, 1782L, 1786L, 
1781L, 1785L, 1783L, 1784L, 1783L, 1784L, 1784L, 1781L, 1787L, 
1781L, 1785L, 1782L, 1784L, 1790L, 1795L, 1793L, 1780L, 1782L, 
1788L, 1787L, 1788L, 1781L, 1781L, 1788L, 1782L, 1783L, 1780L, 
1785L, 1784L, 1781L, 1786L, 1781L, 1787L, 1794L, 1792L, 1791L, 
1781L, 1779L, 1781L, 1781L, 1782L, 1784L, 1783L, 1785L, 1785L, 
1785L, 1781L, 1778L, 1782L, 1784L, 1786L, 1786L, 1784L, 1782L, 
1779L, 1781L, 1782L, 1785L, 1783L, 1782L, 1784L, 1779L, 1785L, 
1784L, 1787L, 1785L, 1786L, 1789L, 1788L, 1785L, 1785L, 1785L, 
1783L, 1784L, 1786L, 1784L, 1782L, 1779L, 1782L, 1787L, 1788L, 
1782L, 1786L, 1784L, 1783L, 1782L, 1785L, 1785L, 1786L, 1786L, 
1786L, 1785L, 1785L, 1789L, 1786L, 1781L, 1785L, 1784L, 1787L, 
1781L, 1788L, 1783L, 1786L, 1786L, 1786L, 1783L, 1788L, 1788L, 
1781L, 1787L, 1791L, 1784L, 1784L, 1785L, 1784L, 1784L, 1782L, 
1779L, 1777L, 1780L, 1783L, 1782L, 1780L, 1781L, 1785L, 1780L, 
1783L, 1786L, 1784L, 1779L, 1785L, 1784L, 1783L, 1783L, 1783L, 
1783L, 1785L, 1781L, 1778L, 1781L, 1785L, 1781L, 1782L, 1788L, 
1782L, 1783L, 1781L, 1786L, 1781L, 1784L, 1782L, 1783L, 1787L, 
1783L, 1786L, 1783L, 1780L, 1781L, 1779L, 1781L, 1784L, 1785L, 
1782L, 1785L, 1785L, 1783L, 1781L, 1780L, 1780L, 1781L, 1779L, 
1780L, 1783L, 1782L, 1786L, 1780L, 1785L, 1786L, 1781L, 1783L, 
1783L, 1788L, 1783L, 1786L, 1788L, 1786L, 1783L, 1784L, 1788L, 
1787L, 1785L, 1785L, 1784L, 1782L, 1785L, 1785L, 1784L, 1781L, 
1788L, 1785L, 1785L, 1786L, 1785L, 1786L, 1787L, 1781L, 1787L, 
1782L, 1781L, 1786L, 1781L, 1783L, 1782L, 1786L, 1786L, 1788L, 
1781L, 1781L, 1783L, 1784L, 1783L, 1781L, 1788L, 1785L, 1779L, 
1786L, 1781L, 1781L, 1787L, 1784L, 1788L, 1782L, 1786L, 1787L, 
1780L, 1785L, 1788L, 1783L, 1783L, 1785L, 1780L, 1780L, 1788L, 
1784L, 1782L, 1787L, 1782L, 1783L, 1782L, 1782L, 1786L, 1784L, 
1788L, 1783L, 1785L, 1786L, 1781L, 1784L, 1782L, 1792L, 1784L, 
1782L, 1780L, 1784L, 1782L, 1783L, 1785L, 1783L, 1787L, 1785L, 
1785L, 1781L, 1787L, 1785L, 1787L, 1783L, 1780L, 1780L, 1785L, 
1783L, 1786L, 1784L, 1783L, 1782L, 1782L, 1789L, 1783L, 1786L, 
1785L, 1783L, 1787L, 1788L, 1783L, 1783L, 1786L, 1783L, 1786L, 
1782L, 1787L, 1782L, 1784L, 1782L, 1786L, 1787L, 1788L, 1788L, 
1782L, 1786L, 1780L, 1785L, 1779L, 1779L, 1779L, 1779L, 1779L, 
1783L, 1783L, 1782L, 1786L, 1785L, 1783L, 1781L, 1780L, 1784L, 
1779L, 1785L, 1780L, 1779L, 1780L, 1779L, 1780L, 1782L, 1783L, 
1781L, 1785L, 1783L, 1786L, 1779L, 1781L, 1781L, 1781L, 1780L, 
1781L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1781L, 1781L, 1781L, 1781L, 
1781L, 1781L, 1780L, 1780L, 1781L, 1786L, 1780L, 1781L, 1780L, 
1780L, 1795L, 1790L, 1793L, 1786L, 1784L, 1782L, 1784L, 1783L, 
1788L, 1787L, 1786L, 1778L, 1783L, 1786L, 1784L, 1783L, 1785L, 
1786L, 1780L, 1786L, 1786L, 1785L, 1782L, 1782L, 1786L, 1784L, 
1787L, 1789L, 1788L, 1782L, 1783L, 1787L, 1783L, 1786L, 1782L, 
1782L, 1786L, 1783L, 1785L, 1788L, 1788L, 1787L, 1783L, 1788L, 
1783L, 1782L, 1782L, 1786L, 1789L, 1784L, 1785L, 1780L, 1781L, 
1786L, 1786L, 1788L, 1785L, 1781L, 1786L, 1785L, 1782L, 1780L, 
1784L, 1781L, 1779L, 1785L, 1786L, 1779L, 1782L, 1783L, 1783L, 
1780L, 1783L, 1782L, 1786L, 1779L, 1780L, 1781L, 1786L, 1783L, 
1785L, 1786L, 1782L, 1787L, 1784L, 1786L, 1786L, 1785L, 1786L, 
1785L, 1784L, 1787L, 1784L, 1784L, 1788L, 1785L, 1784L, 1782L, 
1783L, 1785L, 1782L, 1787L, 1781L, 1782L, 1785L, 1782L, 1786L, 
1785L, 1787L, 1787L, 1786L, 1787L, 1780L, 1785L, 1784L, 1783L, 
1782L, 1787L, 1779L, 1779L, 1786L, 1780L, 1787L, 1781L, 1778L, 
1782L, 1779L, 1778L, 1780L, 1786L, 1779L, 1785L, 1784L, 1779L, 
1784L, 1781L, 1784L, 1782L, 1785L, 1783L, 1781L, 1786L, 1780L, 
1781L, 1780L, 1781L, 1784L, 1787L, 1779L, 1786L, 1781L, 1782L, 
1780L, 1782L, 1786L, 1786L, 1787L, 1782L, 1788L, 1783L, 1785L, 
1788L, 1785L, 1786L, 1787L, 1787L, 1785L, 1784L, 1784L, 1787L, 
1788L, 1787L, 1782L, 1786L, 1784L, 1783L, 1786L, 1782L, 1782L, 
1789L, 1784L, 1783L, 1793L, 1794L, 1793L, 1787L, 1783L, 1782L, 
1786L, 1784L, 1787L, 1783L, 1783L, 1786L, 1789L, 1781L, 1785L, 
1784L, 1788L, 1789L, 1782L, 1784L, 1784L, 1787L, 1787L, 1783L, 
1784L, 1784L, 1783L, 1786L, 1783L, 1785L, 1788L, 1787L, 1788L, 
1783L, 1784L, 1783L, 1783L, 1781L, 1784L, 1786L, 1782L, 1791L, 
1787L, 1781L, 1787L, 1785L, 1787L, 1783L, 1785L, 1782L, 1784L, 
1787L, 1784L, 1783L, 1783L, 1783L, 1784L, 1786L, 1787L, 1782L, 
1789L, 1782L, 1782L, 1783L, 1782L, 1783L, 1783L, 1784L, 1783L, 
1788L, 1786L, 1782L, 1784L, 1781L, 1786L, 1782L, 1779L, 1780L, 
1783L, 1780L, 1786L, 1780L, 1786L, 1784L, 1784L, 1785L, 1777L, 
1783L, 1780L, 1784L, 1783L, 1780L, 1784L, 1781L, 1785L, 1785L, 
1781L, 1780L, 1786L, 1788L, 1787L, 1791L, 1789L, 1787L, 1787L, 
1793L, 1781L, 1784L, 1781L, 1784L, 1779L, 1784L, 1784L, 1784L, 
1780L, 1780L, 1784L, 1787L, 1782L, 1781L, 1784L, 1787L, 1785L, 
1781L, 1785L, 1783L, 1782L, 1782L, 1785L, 1781L, 1782L, 1786L, 
1788L, 1780L, 1787L, 1784L, 1788L, 1787L, 1784L, 1784L, 1785L, 
1780L, 1786L, 1780L, 1780L, 1788L, 1782L, 1793L, 1783L, 1785L, 
1785L, 1781L, 1783L, 1783L, 1787L, 1783L, 1784L, 1784L, 1783L, 
1785L, 1787L, 1788L, 1784L, 1787L, 1787L, 1785L, 1786L, 1784L, 
1786L, 1784L, 1786L, 1787L)

Z <- c(1788L, 1792L, 1787L, 1791L, 1790L, 1789L, 1791L, 1788L, 1792L, 
1794L, 1793L, 1791L, 1792L, 1787L, 1792L, 1792L, 1791L, 1788L, 
1792L, 1794L, 1791L, 1788L, 1794L, 1794L, 1789L, 1792L, 1788L, 
1793L, 1792L, 1788L, 1786L, 1787L, 1791L, 1786L, 1788L, 1792L, 
1787L, 1785L, 1786L, 1790L, 1788L, 1790L, 1792L, 1788L, 1787L, 
1790L, 1786L, 1792L, 1789L, 1787L, 1786L, 1787L, 1793L, 1793L, 
1792L, 1789L, 1786L, 1795L, 1793L, 1788L, 1791L, 1790L, 1792L, 
1790L, 1794L, 1792L, 1789L, 1791L, 1794L, 1788L, 1788L, 1794L, 
1794L, 1792L, 1790L, 1789L, 1788L, 1788L, 1789L, 1789L, 1794L, 
1790L, 1787L, 1791L, 1789L, 1791L, 1790L, 1783L, 1782L, 1781L, 
1781L, 1793L, 1788L, 1795L, 1793L, 1789L, 1791L, 1793L, 1792L, 
1792L, 1784L, 1781L, 1782L, 1795L, 1788L, 1789L, 1793L, 1793L, 
1792L, 1791L, 1791L, 1790L, 1794L, 1792L, 1796L, 1793L, 1791L, 
1793L, 1790L, 1794L, 1795L, 1788L, 1789L, 1790L, 1790L, 1793L, 
1790L, 1795L, 1793L, 1792L, 1778L, 1784L, 1782L, 1791L, 1793L, 
1791L, 1794L, 1793L, 1793L, 1790L, 1792L, 1788L, 1786L, 1790L, 
1794L, 1794L, 1791L, 1787L, 1792L, 1790L, 1791L, 1799L, 1790L, 
1788L, 1795L, 1791L, 1792L, 1787L, 1788L, 1792L, 1795L, 1786L, 
1785L, 1778L, 1794L, 1790L, 1794L, 1792L, 1793L, 1793L, 1793L, 
1792L, 1791L, 1794L, 1791L, 1788L, 1789L, 1790L, 1794L, 1793L, 
1793L, 1791L, 1791L, 1795L, 1790L, 1790L, 1788L, 1793L, 1793L, 
1786L, 1788L, 1795L, 1790L, 1781L, 1781L, 1782L, 1786L, 1794L, 
1787L, 1787L, 1782L, 1786L, 1783L, 1788L, 1784L)
```

Comment: this is an optimization problem. you can take a look at `lpSolve` using 15 binary variables for each element in X, Y and Z. the sum of binary variables, xi, of X = 2, sum of binary variables, yi, for Y = 4 and zi for Z, 3. obj fn is to min `abs(sum(xi*X+yi*Y+zi*Z) - 50)`

Comment: Thanks for the lpSolve package, I'm gonna take a look at it.

Comment: Saw your comment below. It might be slow also if you use lpSolve due to dimensionality issue. U might need to use some sort of heuristics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with the function `MixedCombnPerm` which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682271/mixed-combinations-permutations-from-different-sets).

This solution consists in deriving all possible combinations and then taking the best one(s).

```
X <-  c(2,3,5,10,15) 
Y <- c(4,6,23,15,12) 
Z <- c(23,34,12,1,5)

set_list <- list(X, Y, Z)
k <- c(2, 4, 3)

combinations <- MixedCombnPerm(set_list, k)
total <- colSums(combinations)
deviation <- abs(total - 50)
is <- which(deviation == min(deviation))
combinations[, is]
# [1]  2  3  4  6 15 12 12  1  5
total[is]
# [1] 60
```

---

Here is a solution with `CVXR`. The small values in the results actually are 0.

```
library(CVXR)
x <- Bool(5)
y <- Bool(5)
z <- Bool(5)
constraintX <- sum(x) == 2
constraintY <- sum(y) == 4
constraintZ <- sum(z) == 3
objective <- Minimize((sum(x*X+y*Y+z*Z) - 50)^2)
problem <- Problem(objective, 
                   constraints = list(constraintX, constraintY, constraintZ))
result <- solve(problem)
result$getValue(x)
#              [,1]
# [1,] 1.000000e+00
# [2,] 1.000000e+00
# [3,] 1.168141e-09
# [4,] 8.964959e-11
# [5,] 2.563038e-11
result$getValue(y)
#              [,1]
# [1,] 1.000000e+00
# [2,] 1.000000e+00
# [3,] 1.841415e-10
# [4,] 1.000000e+00
# [5,] 1.000000e+00
result$getValue(z)
#              [,1]
# [1,] 9.946796e-11
# [2,] 3.816320e-11
# [3,] 1.000000e+00
# [4,] 1.000000e+00
# [5,] 1.000000e+00
```

---

## EDIT

Here is a solution using `CVXR` for your large data. First, install the package `Rglpk`:

```
install.packages("Rglpk")
```

Then do:

```
result <- solve(problem, solver = "GLPK")
```

I tested it with

```
objective <- Minimize( abs( sum(x*X) + sum(y*Y) + sum(z*Z) - target) )
```

and it worked.

Comment: I tried to use all combinations, it works great when you have small data but not when  the group of data gets bigger.

I get this error, which I assume it's because I can't handle over 2^31 - 1 combinations...
`Error in CombinatoricsRcpp(v, m, repetition, freqs, lower, upper, constraintFun,  : 
  The number of rows cannot exceed 2^31 - 1.`

Comment: @AuronusBen See my edited answer for another solution.

Comment: Thanks for the second solution. Im gonna try and make it works on my data.

Comment: Thank you Stéphane the second solution seems to work with my large data. 
I just wanna know if you have a document on the theorie behind CVXR?

Comment: @AuronusBen I don't know. Maybe take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Stéphane. I've changed your code to:`target <- 362007
x <- Bool(length(X))
y <- Bool(length(Y))
z <- Bool(length(Z))
constraintX <- sum(x) == 12
constraintY <- sum(y) == 56
constraintZ <- sum(z) == 137
objective <- Minimize( ( sum(x*X) +  sum(y*Y)  + sum(z*Z) -  target)^2 )` because my 3 groups are not the same size in reality. 
But When I change the target value, I get `result$getValue(x) <- NA`

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @AuronusBen I don't know... can you share the data ?

Comment: My data is in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58979392/12322285

Comment: I deleted my answer and I edited my first post. Thanks again Stéphane.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58972181/12322285

Comment: @AuronusBen Ok. For which value of target it doesn't work ?

Comment: For example: 366024
I don't understand why it does not get me the closest values to 366024...

Comment: @AuronusBen See my edit. Looks like the GLPK solver is better.

Comment: Thank You so much Stéphane. It's working better with GLPK.  Thank you again !

Comment: @AuronusBen Yes, it is incredibly fast. Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `outer()` can help you, but the efficiency may be low when with large dataset:

```
k <- c(2,4,3)

L <- list(X,Y,Z)
V <- sapply(seq_along(k), function(q) combn(L[[q]],k[q]))
S <- abs(Reduce(function(x,y) outer(x,y,"+"), Map(colSums,V))-50)
r <- as.numeric(which(S == min(S),arr.ind = T))
res <- sapply(seq_along(r), function(q) V[[q]][,r[q]])
```

which gives:

```
> res
$X
[1] 2 3

$Y
[1]  4  6 15 12

$Z
[1] 12  1  5
```

Comment: Sadly like I said combinations work great with small data. But When I get bigger data it's not possible anymore.
I get  `invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA) ` which mean the data is way too big.

Comment: @AuronusBen How large is your dataset? Just curious

Comment: In reality:
`Length(X) = 304`
`length(Y) = 205`
and `length(Z) = 1057`.
I want to take the best: 12 values from X, 56 values from Y and 137 values from Z.


that's why I cant use combinations because I cant handle them.

Comment: @AuronusBen Maybe you should try the solution provided by @Stéphane Laurent, i.e., using `CVXR`